# error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I am using Unity 4.3 for developing a card game as my learning process. Below is the code. On line 19 and line 24 of this code, I am getting the following error 
**error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer**

```
public class DebugCHangeCard : MonoBehaviour {
    Rect rectangle = new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100, "Hit me");
    public GameObject card;

    void Start () {
        card = GameObject.Find("Card");
    }

    public Card_Model cardmodel;
    int cardindex = 0;
    void Awake()
    {

        cardmodel = card.GetComponent<Card_Model>();
    }

    void onGUI()
    {

        if (GUI.Button(rectangle))
        {
            cardmodel.cardIndex = cardindex;
            cardmodel.toggleFace = true;
            cardindex++;
            if (cardindex == 52)
            {
                cardindex = 0;
                cardmodel.toggleFace = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to figure out the problem. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could point out which lines are 19 and 24.

Comment: Don't use anything that requires `OnGUI` or `GUI.XXX`. [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) you can find information about creating UI in Unity.

Comment: I am getting this error before and after this line error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer

Comment: S.Akbari I am new to Unity. I have googled the problem but still unable to figure it out

Comment: I bet `cardmodel.toggleFace` is a method, and not a property or field.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma, it is a property.